# Is there a way to read specific values of a row in python 3 for csv file?

Tags: python, csv

I would like to do read only the value of the last column `Existing Policies` through the input of `Customer NRIC` number. For example, when I input `S876XXXXF`, the output should give me existing policies: `Investments and Travel`.

Here is the csv file data:

```
Customer NRIC,Customer Name,Date of Birth,Existing Policies
S876XXXXF,John Tan,7-Oct-87,Investments and Travel
T019XXXXA,Alice Lim,14-Apr-01,Savings 
S921XXXXK,Sam Chua,19-Aug-92,Savings and Investment
```

Here is what I have coded so far and got stuck:

```
import csv

filename = "database.csv"
nric = input("Enter your NRIC number: ")

file = open(filename,"r")

with open("database.csv") as customer_info:
    csv_pointer = csv.reader(customer_info)
    for each in csv_pointer:
        print(each[-1])
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('database.csv') as csvfile:
    csv_pointer = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in csv_pointer:
        print(row)
```

Firstly, do this, and you'll begin to understand what the individual variables are storing. Then I believe you should be able to do the rest of the code to only output the specific NRIC number. Below is the solution if you're still unable to get it.

```
nric = input("Enter your NRIC number: ")
with open('database.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    csv_pointer = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in csv_pointer:
        if row[0]==nric:
            print(row[-1])
```

Comment: do you know if i want to add an error message after the print(row[-1]) for those data that does not match any of my data in the csv file?